# ERROR: Could not build wheels for thriftpy2, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, macos

When I `pip install thriftpy2`some error occurred.

Env Base Info:

```
CPU: M1(10-core 64-bit westmere)
Clang: 14.0.0 build 1400
Git: 2.41.0 => /usr/local/bin/git
Curl: 7.79.1 => /usr/bin/curl
macOS: 12.5.1-x86_64
CLT: 14.2.0.0.1.1668646533
Xcode: N/A
Rosetta 2: true
Python 3.10.8
Conda 23.5.0
```

Error Details:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: thriftpy2
  Building wheel for thriftpy2 (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [277 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      The [wheel] section is deprecated. Use [bdist_wheel] instead.
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310
      creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2
      copying thriftpy2/server.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2
      copying thriftpy2/hook.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2
      copying thriftpy2/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2
      copying thriftpy2/thrift.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2
      copying thriftpy2/rpc.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2
      copying thriftpy2/utils.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2
      copying thriftpy2/tornado.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2
      copying thriftpy2/http.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2
      copying thriftpy2/_compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2
      creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/transport
      copying thriftpy2/transport/_ssl.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/transport
      copying thriftpy2/transport/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/transport
      copying thriftpy2/transport/sslsocket.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/transport
      copying thriftpy2/transport/socket.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/transport
      copying thriftpy2/transport/base.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/transport
      creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/protocol
      copying thriftpy2/protocol/binary.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/protocol
      copying thriftpy2/protocol/apache_json.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/protocol
      copying thriftpy2/protocol/compact.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/protocol
      copying thriftpy2/protocol/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/protocol
      copying thriftpy2/protocol/exc.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/protocol
      copying thriftpy2/protocol/multiplex.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/protocol
      copying thriftpy2/protocol/json.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/protocol
      copying thriftpy2/protocol/base.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/protocol
      creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/parser
      copying thriftpy2/parser/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/parser
      copying thriftpy2/parser/parser.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/parser
      copying thriftpy2/parser/exc.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/parser
      copying thriftpy2/parser/lexer.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/parser
      creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/contrib
      copying thriftpy2/contrib/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/contrib
      creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/transport/memory
      copying thriftpy2/transport/memory/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/transport/memory
      creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/transport/buffered
      copying thriftpy2/transport/buffered/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/transport/buffered
      creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/transport/framed
      copying thriftpy2/transport/framed/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/transport/framed
      creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/contrib/aio
      copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/server.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/contrib/aio
      copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/client.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/contrib/aio
      copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/contrib/aio
      copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/processor.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/contrib/aio
      copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/rpc.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/contrib/aio
      copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/socket.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/contrib/aio
      creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/contrib/tracking
      copying thriftpy2/contrib/tracking/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/contrib/tracking
      copying thriftpy2/contrib/tracking/tracker.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/contrib/tracking
      creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/contrib/aio/transport
      copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/transport/buffered.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/contrib/aio/transport
      copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/transport/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/contrib/aio/transport
      copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/transport/base.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/contrib/aio/transport
      copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/transport/framed.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/contrib/aio/transport
      creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/contrib/aio/protocol
      copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/protocol/binary.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/contrib/aio/protocol
      copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/protocol/compact.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/contrib/aio/protocol
      copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/protocol/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/contrib/aio/protocol
      copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/protocol/base.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/contrib/aio/protocol
      running egg_info
      writing thriftpy2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to thriftpy2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to thriftpy2.egg-info/requires.txt
      writing top-level names to thriftpy2.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'thriftpy2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'thriftpy2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      ~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_py.py:201: _Warning: Package 'thriftpy2.protocol.cybin' is absent from the `packages` configuration.
      !!
      
              ********************************************************************************
              ############################
              # Package would be ignored #
              ############################
              Python recognizes 'thriftpy2.protocol.cybin' as an importable package[^1],
              but it is absent from setuptools' `packages` configuration.
      
              This leads to an ambiguous overall configuration. If you want to distribute this
              package, please make sure that 'thriftpy2.protocol.cybin' is explicitly added
              to the `packages` configuration field.
      
              Alternatively, you can also rely on setuptools' discovery methods
              (for example by using `find_namespace_packages(...)`/`find_namespace:`
              instead of `find_packages(...)`/`find:`).
      
              You can read more about "package discovery" on setuptools documentation page:
      
              - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html
      
              If you don't want 'thriftpy2.protocol.cybin' to be distributed and are
              already explicitly excluding 'thriftpy2.protocol.cybin' via
              `find_namespace_packages(...)/find_namespace` or `find_packages(...)/find`,
              you can try to use `exclude_package_data`, or `include-package-data=False` in
              combination with a more fine grained `package-data` configuration.
      
              You can read more about "package data files" on setuptools documentation page:
      
              - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html
      
      
              [^1]: For Python, any directory (with suitable naming) can be imported,
                    even if it does not contain any `.py` files.
                    On the other hand, currently there is no concept of package data
                    directory, all directories are treated like packages.
              ********************************************************************************
      
      !!
        check.warn(importable)
      copying thriftpy2/transport/cybase.c -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/transport
      copying thriftpy2/transport/cybase.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/transport
      copying thriftpy2/transport/cybase.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/transport
      creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/protocol/cybin
      copying thriftpy2/protocol/cybin/cybin.c -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/protocol/cybin
      copying thriftpy2/protocol/cybin/cybin.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/protocol/cybin
      copying thriftpy2/protocol/cybin/endian_port.h -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/protocol/cybin
      copying thriftpy2/transport/memory/cymemory.c -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/transport/memory
      copying thriftpy2/transport/memory/cymemory.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/transport/memory
      copying thriftpy2/transport/buffered/cybuffered.c -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/transport/buffered
      copying thriftpy2/transport/buffered/cybuffered.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/transport/buffered
      copying thriftpy2/transport/framed/cyframed.c -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/transport/framed
      copying thriftpy2/transport/framed/cyframed.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/transport/framed
      copying thriftpy2/contrib/tracking/tracking.thrift -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/contrib/tracking
      running build_ext
      building 'thriftpy2.transport.cybase' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310
      creating build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2
      creating build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/transport
      arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem ~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/include -arch arm64 -fPIC -O2 -isystem ~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/include -arch arm64 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -isystem ~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem ~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/include -I~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/include/python3.10 -c thriftpy2/transport/cybase.c -o build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/transport/cybase.o
      arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -Wl,-rpath,~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib -L~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib -Wl,-rpath,~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib -L~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib -Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs -Wl,-rpath,~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib -L~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -isystem ~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem ~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/include build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/transport/cybase.o -o build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/transport/cybase.cpython-310-darwin.so
      ld: warning: -pie being ignored. It is only used when linking a main executable
      building 'thriftpy2.transport.buffered.cybuffered' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/transport/buffered
      arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem ~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/include -arch arm64 -fPIC -O2 -isystem ~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/include -arch arm64 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -isystem ~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem ~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/include -I~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/include/python3.10 -c thriftpy2/transport/buffered/cybuffered.c -o build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/transport/buffered/cybuffered.o
      arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -Wl,-rpath,~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib -L~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib -Wl,-rpath,~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib -L~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib -Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs -Wl,-rpath,~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib -L~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -isystem ~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem ~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/include build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/transport/buffered/cybuffered.o -o build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/transport/buffered/cybuffered.cpython-310-darwin.so
      ld: warning: -pie being ignored. It is only used when linking a main executable
      building 'thriftpy2.transport.memory.cymemory' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/transport/memory
      arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem ~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/include -arch arm64 -fPIC -O2 -isystem ~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/include -arch arm64 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -isystem ~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem ~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/include -I~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/include/python3.10 -c thriftpy2/transport/memory/cymemory.c -o build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/transport/memory/cymemory.o
      arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -Wl,-rpath,~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib -L~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib -Wl,-rpath,~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib -L~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib -Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs -Wl,-rpath,~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib -L~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -isystem ~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem ~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/include build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/transport/memory/cymemory.o -o build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/transport/memory/cymemory.cpython-310-darwin.so
      ld: warning: -pie being ignored. It is only used when linking a main executable
      building 'thriftpy2.transport.framed.cyframed' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/transport/framed
      arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem ~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/include -arch arm64 -fPIC -O2 -isystem ~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/include -arch arm64 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -isystem ~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem ~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/include -I~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/include/python3.10 -c thriftpy2/transport/framed/cyframed.c -o build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/transport/framed/cyframed.o
      arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -Wl,-rpath,~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib -L~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib -Wl,-rpath,~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib -L~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib -Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs -Wl,-rpath,~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib -L~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -isystem ~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem ~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/include build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/transport/framed/cyframed.o -o build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/transport/framed/cyframed.cpython-310-darwin.so
      ld: warning: -pie being ignored. It is only used when linking a main executable
      building 'thriftpy2.protocol.cybin' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/protocol
      creating build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/protocol/cybin
      arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem ~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/include -arch arm64 -fPIC -O2 -isystem ~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/include -arch arm64 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -isystem ~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem ~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/include -I~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/include/python3.10 -c thriftpy2/protocol/cybin/cybin.c -o build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/protocol/cybin/cybin.o
      arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -Wl,-rpath,~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib -L~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib -Wl,-rpath,~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib -L~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib -Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs -Wl,-rpath,~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib -L~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -isystem ~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem ~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/include build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/protocol/cybin/cybin.o -o build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/protocol/cybin.cpython-310-darwin.so
      ld: warning: -pie being ignored. It is only used when linking a main executable
      ~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py:66: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated.
      !!
      
              ********************************************************************************
              Please avoid running ``setup.py`` directly.
              Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/installer, pypa/build or
              other standards-based tools.
      
              See https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html for details.
              ********************************************************************************
      
      !!
        self.initialize_options()
      installing to build/bdist.macosx-11.0-arm64/wheel
      running install
      running install_lib
      creating build/bdist.macosx-11.0-arm64
      creating build/bdist.macosx-11.0-arm64/wheel
      creating build/bdist.macosx-11.0-arm64/wheel/thriftpy2
      copying build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/server.py -> build/bdist.macosx-11.0-arm64/wheel/thriftpy2
      creating build/bdist.macosx-11.0-arm64/wheel/thriftpy2/transport
      copying build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/transport/_ssl.py -> build/bdist.macosx-11.0-arm64/wheel/thriftpy2/transport
      creating build/bdist.macosx-11.0-arm64/wheel/thriftpy2/transport/memory
      copying ...
      creating build/bdist.macosx-11.0-arm64/wheel/thriftpy2/transport/buffered
      copying ...
      creating build/bdist.macosx-11.0-arm64/wheel/thriftpy2/transport/framed
      copying something...
      creating build/bdist.macosx-11.0-arm64/wheel/thriftpy2/protocol
      copying something...
      creating build/bdist.macosx-11.0-arm64/wheel/thriftpy2/protocol/cybin
      copying something...
      creating build/bdist.macosx-11.0-arm64/wheel/thriftpy2/parser
      copying something...
      creating build/bdist.macosx-11.0-arm64/wheel/thriftpy2/contrib
      copying build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/contrib/__init__.py -> build/bdist.macosx-11.0-arm64/wheel/thriftpy2/contrib
      creating build/bdist.macosx-11.0-arm64/wheel/thriftpy2/contrib/aio
      copying build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/thriftpy2/contrib/aio/server.py -> build/bdist.macosx-11.0-arm64/wheel/thriftpy2/contrib/aio
      creating build/bdist.macosx-11.0-arm64/wheel/thriftpy2/contrib/aio/transport
      copying something...
      creating build/bdist.macosx-11.0-arm64/wheel/thriftpy2/contrib/aio/protocol
      copying something...
      creating build/bdist.macosx-11.0-arm64/wheel/thriftpy2/contrib/tracking
      copying something...
      running install_egg_info
      Copying thriftpy2.egg-info to build/bdist.macosx-11.0-arm64/wheel/thriftpy2-0.4.16-py3.10.egg-info
      running install_scripts
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/rx/2h26x2c17dq3ntcr8g9dl67r0000gn/T/pip-install-hw7ktz0x/thriftpy2_071a76a186d743c88526c39c0fa8cfb9/setup.py", line 76, in <module>
          setup(name="thriftpy2",
        File "~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 107, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1244, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 328, in run
          impl_tag, abi_tag, plat_tag = self.get_tag()
        File "~/anaconda3/envs/mtbi-python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 278, in get_tag
          assert tag in supported_tags, "would build wheel with unsupported tag {}".format(tag)
      AssertionError: would build wheel with unsupported tag ('cp310', 'cp310', 'macosx_11_0_arm64')
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for thriftpy2
  Running setup.py clean for thriftpy2
Failed to build thriftpy2
ERROR: Could not build wheels for thriftpy2, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects.
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by update `wheel` to `0.40.0`.